# Java For Loop and User Input

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, user-input

I am fairly new to Java programming and have been using a for loop in my program.  I noticed whenever my program asks for user input, that whenever I press the enter key that is used as the next key for the second iteration of the loop.  Is there a way to make this not occur?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read input with multiple lines in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296685/how-to-read-input-with-multiple-lines-in-java)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question really needs a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to go with it. Cheers. Also do check out the other answer @funky mentions.

Answer (score 1):

Use while loop instead:

```
while(true){
          String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter something.");//take inputs while have not encountered STOP
          if(input.equals("STOP")){
              System.exit(0);
          }
 }
```